# How to tell NDSolve about known relations of the exact solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

The solution to this system of differential equations:

```
NDSolve[{
    x''[t] == k[t] y'[t], y''[t] == -k[t] x'[t], 
    x'[0] == A, y'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}, 
  {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

satisfies this equation:

```
x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 == A
```

But when `NDSolve` solves the system, the speed will eventually move away from it's initial value `A`.

Is there anyway to make `NDSolve` keep the speed normalized?

Comment: @ Coolwater: This can be easily done: eliminate y'[t] from x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2==A^2, i.e. y'[t] = +-Sqrt[A^2-x'[t]^2]. Then your only remaining equation will be {x''[t]==+-k[t] Sqrt[A^2-x'[t]^2],x'[0] == A, x[0] == 0}. After specifying k(t), A and the sign of the Sqrt you can NSolve it.

Comment: I don't understand how that is useful. When the order of the equation system is reduced to 3, how would I know what the sign of the Sqrt is? It's needed for both `y'[t]` and `x''[t]`, so only `x'[t]`and `k[t]` is available to determine it, which I believe is impossible?!

Comment: you should just NDSolve the equation for both signs and then look how they fit together.

Comment: BTW the system describes the motion of a charged particle in the x-y-plane in a time-dependent magnetic field along the z-axis given by k(t). It leads to interesting trajectories. Take k(t) = t or k(t) = Sin(t/5) for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is (unspecified `k[t]`, `A`) `NDSolve` will not work. However the equations can be handled analytically.
After a simple manipulation you can decouple them and get :

```
rawx[t_] = x[t] /. DSolve[{k[t] x'''[t] - k'[t] x''[t] == -k[t]^3 x'[t]}, x[t], t]

rawy[t_] = y[t] /. First@DSolve[{D[#, {t, 2}]/k[t] == y'[t]}, y[t], t] & /@ rawx[t]
```

Now you can check that indeed :

```
rawx'[t]^2 + rawy'[t]^2 // Simplify
(* {-2 C[1], -2 C[1]} *)
```

A quicker way is to rename `x'[t]->m[t], y'[t]->y[t]` and then :

```
raw = DSolve[{m'[t] == k[t] n[t], n'[t] == -k[t] m[t]}, {m[t], n[t]}, t]
sol[t_] = {m[t], n[t]} /. First@raw

sol[t]^2 // Total // Simplify
(* C[1]^2 + C[2]^2 *)
```